# Problema con método onClick en BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

El problema es que tengo `ListView` y necesito que al hacer click en un item me vaya a otro `Fragment` siendo este BaseAdapter.

```
public class UsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public List<User> allUsers;

    private Context  context;

    /*************
     * Constructor
     *****************/
    public UsersAdapter(Context  ctx, ArrayList<User> data) {


        context = ctx;
        allUsers = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allUsers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;

        UserViewHolder holder = new UserViewHolder();

        final User user = allUsers.get(position);


        if(convertView==null)
        {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boxer_item, null);
            holder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img_user);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (UserViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }


        holder.name.setText(user.getName());

        Glide.with(context).load(user.getImage()).into(holder.icon);


       rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              //  Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              if (user.getName().equals("Ramon \nDekkers")) {

                   Fragment fragment = new Ramon_dekkers();
                   FragmentManager fragmentManager = context.getFragmentManager(); -> Eso falla
                   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment); -> Y aqui
                   fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); //If you want to add to back stack
                   fragmentTransaction.commit();

               }

            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }


    private static class UserViewHolder {
        public ImageView icon;
        public TextView name;

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar bien que problema tienes? ¿Te muestra algo en el _LogCat_?

Comment: De momento, no me lo ha conseguido solucionar absolutamente nadie. Te cuento, a ver, tengo un ``ListView`` con ciertos items, en concreto 12, y necesito que al hacer click en uno de ellos, me lleve a un``Fragment``. Este ``ListView`` también está en un ``Fragment``.

Comment: El problema está donde pone esto  **// AQUÍ ES DONDE NECESITO PONER DE IR A OTRO FRAGMENT, ¿CÓMO?**

Comment: Actualizo y te pongo lo que tengo y no me deja compilar porque me da error.

Comment: Lo que estoy diciendo, y parece que da miedo a la gente, es si alguien puede ser tan amable de darme su skype, su cuenta, su email, lo que sea, para poder ayudarme y explicarle mejor y que dure esto 5 min, no 50, porque por aqui es realmente explicar algo si no es pregunta directa.

Comment: O incluso enviar el el .rar de mi codigo que simplemente es importarlo y ya y así en 1 minuto se ve donde esta el fallo. Sabes x4mp73r?

Comment: Es un problema que necesito enviar el .rar para verlo directamente , si estoy aquí explicándote lo que me sale en fallos, estamos todo el día, y es realmente importate para mi, llevo preguntando esto dias y dias y perdiendo horas y horas.... sin avanzar nada. Si te interesa ayudarme por favor hazmelo saber. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

1) Al instanciar `UsersAdapter` envia como contexto `getActivity()`.

2) Si tu clase extiende de `AppCompatActivity` debes usar `getSupportFragmentManager()` en lugar de `getFragmentManager()`

---

<strike>te comento que el problema es que tratas de implementar un `OnClickListener` en el layout `boxer_item.xml`</strike>

```
rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boxer_item, null);
rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        ...
```

El listener seguramente no se esta llamando.

Asigna el listener al `ImageView` (icon) o al `TextView` (name) y debe poder realizarse la transacción del fragmento.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47778/discussion-on-answer-by-elenasys-problema-con-metodo-onclick-en-baseadapter).

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente como buena practica no es recomendable recargar el adaptador, una opcion es crear una interfaz en un archivo separado para utilizarlo como Callback de la siguiente forma

```
public interface Callback<T> {
void insertFragment(User user);}
```

Declaras a nivel de tu adaptador

```
private Callback<User> cb;
```

Luego creas un metodo publico en tu adaptador lo esperas de esta manera

```
public void rowCallBack(Callback<User> cb) {this.cb = cb;}
```

Dentro tu evento onClick lo llamas de esta manera

```
cb.insertFragment(user); //"user" es el objeto que estas accesando en ese momento
```

Entonces cuando mandes llamar tu adaptador desde tu activity o fragment se lo pasas de esta manera.

```
  Adapter adapter = new Adapter(context, data);

adapter.rowCallBack(new Callback<User>(){  @Override public void insertFragment(User user){ /**Aqui podes insertar tu frament con getSupportFragmentManager (Dentro de un frament) getFragmentManager (Dentro de un activity)**/ } });
```

Y cuando insertas tu fragment ya no necesitas estar pasando el contexto al adaptador. Si estas dentro de un fragment es **getSupportFragmentManager** y si es dentro de un activity es **getFragmentManager**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = context.getFragmentManager(); -> Eso falla
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment); -> Y aqui
           fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); //If you want to add to back stack
           fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Espero te sea util esta explicacion saludos.